# Why does my Vue app not render, despite the mounted event firing?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

So, here's a curious case. The code works in codepen (and even in stack overflow's code renderer), but not on my github pages site.

No errors fire, and the console logs for the created and mounted events go off fine, but the element does not get rendered on the webpage.

```js
(function() {
  console.log('test', Vue);

  const contentCards = [
    {
      'anchor': 'hero',
      'title': 'Cold Throne Steel',
      'body': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.'
    }
  ];

  Vue.component('content-card', {
    props: ['anchor', 'title', 'body'],
    template: `
    <section class="content-card" v-bind:id="anchor">
    <h1 class="content-card__title">{{ title }}</h1>
    <p class="content-card__body">{{ body }}</p>
    </section>`
  });

  const root = new Vue({
    el: "#main-content",
    created: function() {
      console.log('element has been created')
    },
    mounted: function() {
      console.log('element has been mounted')
    },
    data: {
      cards: contentCards
    }
  });

  console.log('root', root);
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <main id="main-content">
      <content-card v-for="card in cards" v-bind:key="card.anchor" v-bind:anchor="card.anchor" v-bind:title="card.anchor" v-bind:body="card.body"></content-card>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can view the page here: https://coldthronesteel.com/ and see that the Vue app isn't working...despite all console logs suggesting that it should!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to wait for your element to be loaded in DOM before executing your script. One way to do it is by putting your script tag after your element:

```
<main id="main-content">
  <content-card v-for="card in cards" v-bind:key="card.anchor" v-bind:anchor="card.anchor" v-bind:title="card.anchor" v-bind:body="card.body"></content-card>
</main>
<script src="scripts/scripts.js"></script>
```

Or you can use [DOMContentLoaded event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event).

---

<sup>* The reason that it works in CodePen is that it puts the script section before `</body>` tag. It assures the DOM is ready.</sup>

Comment: Yep! That did it...I'm not used to scripts running before the DOM loads, but, it wasn't deferred or anything, so it makes sense.

Comment: @DisvaDravir Happy to hear. If the answer helped and answered your question, you can mark it as an approved answer.